# After closing the Browser in remote machine the script is still running

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am wondering how the script is running even after closing the browser. It is happening while i am running the script in a remote machine in FF browser but it is working fine when i am running the script in local machine...

For closing the browser i am using

I tried with driver.quit() and driver.close(); but the script is still running,,,

How to go about this?..I am using Java as the programming language?

Suppose i have three keyword to run. When the execution gets completed then again all the keywords are start running..I am seeing errors like "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-error-diagnostics/2.2.1/maven-error-diagnostics-2.2.1.pom"

Thanks,

Sudhansu

Comment: I'm a little confused. The title says "Closing the Browser in remote machine is not working" but then you say "After closing the browser the script is still running", which implies the browser did close.

Comment: Also: "Is there any way to handle this type of errors..." What error? You haven't shown us the error.

Comment: Hi CMeriil,I edited the question...

Comment: What script is still running? What errors do you see? Please provide stack traces so we can assist you, thanks.